# laravel model factory seed generate from existing

Tags: laravel-5, factory, laravel-seeding

I am trying to seed a table with a foreign key and I'm stuck on how I would tell the model to randomly pull values from what already exists.

**ModelFactory**

```
$factory->define(App\Vendor::class, function(Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->company,
    ];
});

$factory->define(App\Device::class, function(Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'vendor' => ,
        'name' => $faker->company,
        'mac_address' => $faker->macAddress,
    ];
});
```

**Seeds**

*VendorTableSeeder*

```
public function run()
{
    factory(App\Vendor::class, 150)->create();
}
```

*DeviceTableSeeder*

```
public function run()
{
    factory(App\Device::class, 50)->create();
}
```

*DataSeeder*

```
$this->call(VendorTableSeeder::class);
$this->call(DeviceTableSeeder::class);
```

I seed the Vendor table before the Device table and would like to populate a random vendor id from the existing vendors.

```
'vendor' => 'factory::App\Vendor'
```

But I am getting

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: foreign key constraint fails
```

It looks like the insert is trying to insert `factory::App\Vendor` as a string for the vendor column. I am trying to figure out how to have it pull from the existing vendors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seed them at the same time from the `VendorTableSeeder`.

Will you ever need Devices without Vendors? Or Vendors without Devices? If not, then this is the best option. Related tables should be seeded together.

A better example would be a School. The School is the main seed, and for each School, you would also seed a Principal, several Teachers, and 100 Students. If you seed them all at once that eliminates the concerns about foreign keys or ordering.

```php
factory(App\Vendor::class, 150)
    ->create()
    ->each(function (App\Vendor $vendor) {
        $vendor->devices()->save(
            factory(App\Device::class)->make()
        );

        // For some randomness
        $vendor->devices()->save(
            factory(App\Device::class, rand(0, 4))->make()
        );
    });
```

If you do want the flexibility of seeding them separately then you have a couple other options. You can pull in a random Vendor inside the Device factory itself.

```php
$factory->define(App\Device::class, function(Faker\Generator $faker) {

    // Grab a random vendor
    $vendor = App\Vendor::orderByRaw('RAND()')->first();

    // Or create a new vendor
    $vendor = factory(App\Vendor::class)->create();

    return [
        'vendor_id'   => $vendor->id,
        'name'        => $faker->company,
        'mac_address' => $faker->macAddress,
    ];
});
```

Or you can pass extra attributes which are merged with the factory-generated attributes.

```php
// $vendor is a Vendor object

factory(App\Device::class, 50)->create([
    'vendor_id' => $vendor->id,
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it with my addresses, I made it so 10% of the time it would create a new address otherwise use a random one.

```
// Grab a random address
$address = App\Address::orderByRaw('RAND()')->first();

// 10% that we will generate a new address
if ($faker->boolean(10) || !$address)
{
    $address = factory(App\Address::class)->create();
}
```

Basically I grab a random address, if it exists there is a is a 10% chance that `$faker->boolean(10)` will return `true` and it will generate a new address. However if there is no address (`$address == false`) we always to generate a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple way to generator factory using random() method

```
$factory->define(App\Device::class, function(Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        // another way to, Get any random row from existing records
        'vendor_id' => App\Vendor::all()->random()->user_id,
        'name'        => $faker->company,
        'mac_address' => $faker->macAddress,
    ];
});
```